# System shortcuts not working when using enterFullscreenMode:withOptions:

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an application that at times can bring a view into fullscreen mode on a second display. The application does this by using the "enterFullscreenMode:withOptions" api on the view.

How ever what's odd is that while in fullscreen mode on another display, system shortcuts such as cmd+tab or alt+space doesn't work any more, all normal characters work though. And when I bring the view out of fullscreen mode the keyboard works normally again.

How can I fix this?